# How to send json data ver a socket in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to send a json data to client with json values taken from variables.
Please help to suggest how I can achieve this?

I have tried below code on server side but it does not work

```
# next create a socket object
s = socket.socket()
print("Socket successfully created")


s.bind(('', port))
print("socket binded to %s" % (port))

# put the socket into listening mode
s.listen(5)
print("socket is listening")

message = {'studentname': 'name', 'studentmark': 'marks'}
s,addr = s.accept()
while True:
    tmp = s.recv(1024)
    message += tmp
    d = json.loads(message)
    s.send(d)

print(d)
```

Comment: Is there any error message/ log so someone can help you to identify why it is not working?

Comment: 'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'